# Does the salesforce JavaScript proxy work without API acess?

Tags: apex, javascript, soap

Basically, I'd like to implement a pure JavaScript SOAP call, and I'd like to know if salesforce.com allows the following code in a non-API-enabled Professional Edition:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js"/>
<script>
    sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
    sforce.connection.remoteFunction({ ... });
</script>
```

I don't have an API-disabled org to test with, and I can't find any documentation on if it is allowed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a trial Professional Edition, and proved that I had no API access, but could still call through to a website (Google, for demonstration purposes). Here's the code:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js"/>
<script>
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
function click1() {
    sforce.connection.query('select id from account', { onSuccess: okay, onFailure: fail });
}
function click2() {
    sforce.connection.remoteFunction({ url: 'http://www.google.com/', onSuccess: okay, onFailure: fail });
}
function okay(result) {
    document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = result.toString().replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
}
function fail(error) {

    document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = error.toString().replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
}
</script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<button onclick="click1()">API test</button>
<button onclick="click2()">Remote test</button>
</apex:page>
```

On the one hand, I'm glad I took the time to check and see if this works, because it's the only way to call web services in Professional Edition, while on the other, I hope it's not a bug, because a JS proxy is the only way we can access web services in Professional Edition.

---

API button outputs:

```
{faultcode:'sf:API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG', faultstring:'API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner', detail:{UnexpectedErrorFault:{exceptionCode:'API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG', exceptionMessage:'API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner', }, }, }
```

Remote Function button outputs (contents of Google home page):

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head>...
```

Answer (score 1):

Some PE orgs pay to have access to the API, I believe. Apart from that, a PE org can access the API with special applications created by Salesforce's ISVForce partners that are available on App Exchange.

ISVForce partners get a partner key that allows those apps to get access to the Salesforce APIs even on PE orgs.

So if you are an ISV partner, and writing an ISV app for App Exchange, you'll be in business when your app is installed in someone's org.

Otherwise this will fail as it is a full-fledged API call.

EDIT:
The first two sentences of the AJAX toolkit developer guide are as follows: "The AJAX Toolkit is a JavaScript wrapper around the API. The AJAX Toolkit is available for any organization that has API access."

Comment: I wonder about that. I actually created a read-only profile *without api access* in my EE, and it was able to proxy just fine.

Comment: Edited my original response to add reference from docs. But I'll be honest, I've not tested and I'm surprised that it works for the user with API access disabled (bug?). We probably don't want people doing this too often, but you could sign up for a free PE org and test?

Comment: I've verified the behavior in a fresh PE org without API access. Bug? Maybe, maybe not, but I have a working demonstration.

Comment: There is one little wrinkle...eval orgs sometimes have extra permissions (like being able to write Apex without tests). I'm asking the API PM team to find out more info.

Comment: Hey sfdcfox...could you email me. I'd like to ask you a few questions and get some information from you: pchittum@salesforce.com